# c# Linq to entities .The specified type member 'CityName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I got an error:

> The specified type member 'CityName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

`Timesheet` table in database doesn't have `Employee` field.

How to get the `CityName` field working? Please help. Thanks

```
public class Timesheets : IExcelInitializer
{    
   public int TimesheetId { get; set; }
   public string Network { get; set; }
   public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee 
{    
   public City CityName { get; set; }
}

public class City
{    
   public string CityName { get; set; }
}

var dt = Context.Timesheets
            .Include(a => a.Employee)
            .Where(a => a.TimesheetId == 222)
            .Select(a => new TimesheetExcelRecord 
            {
                id = a.TimesheetId,
                Network = a.Network,
                Location = a.Employee.City.CityName
            } );
```

Comment: What does your model look like? Is there a foreign key relationship between Timesheets and Employee?

Comment: Hard to tell with this bit of information. I assume that `Employee` should have a property `EmployeeId` and that is should have a collection of `TimeSheet`s (make the class name singular).

Comment: What is type of Location, i guess    "Location = a.Employee.CityName" this line is creating problem,

Answer (score 0):

If `Employee` class is not an entity in your model and it's only a class to add information to your `TimeSheet` entity, then you need to map it as a [Complex Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#ComplexType):

```
[ComplexType]
public class Employee 
{    
   public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```